# typeerror: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given (Gunicorn)

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I have made a web app using flask. The app works fine when I run it locally (Gunicorn not invloved at all) but when I deploy the app on Heroku, It raises the following TypeError in console.

```
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446327+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446329+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446329+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446336+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446337+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-03-28T15:42:25.446345+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

My procfile is like this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Gunicorn is installed correctly too.

**Things I have tried:**

- Tried setting procfile too: `web: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app` (Didn't work)
- EDIT: I updated python runtime to `python-3.8.6` and that led to a different error:

```
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246747+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246748+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246749+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246756+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246757+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-03-28T15:49:20.246758+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'
```

- EDIT 2: I was using Quart (Async flask) and when I moved to flask everything worked fine. So, Problem is with Quart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask is a WSGI framework, which works nicely with Gunicorn, a WSGI server. Quart however is an ASGI framework and hence requires an ASGI server. The Quart [docs recommend](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/tutorials/deployment.html) the ASGI server Hypercorn.